# Getting value from request in Laravel using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have this ajax method in PostsController

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
    { 

        //dd($request);
        $this->authorize('view', Post::class);

        $posts = Post::orderBy("created_at","desc")->paginate(5);
        $comments = Comment::all();

        return response()->json(array("posts"=> $posts, "comments"=> $comments), 200);

    }
```

which works great when you just getting data and sending it.
So i tried besides requesting data by ajax, to send some data alongside ajax request. How can i access that data inside controller?

Here is a method which resides inside certain blade:

```
function ajax(){

  let var1 = "gg";
  let var2 = "bruh";
  let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
  let url = '/posts';

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    headers:
        {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
    data: {
        'var1': var1,
        'var2': var2
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  });         

}
```

To simplify: How can i, dd() or dump(), given data(var1 & var2) by ajax function from blade in PostsController?

Here is route:

```
Route::post('/posts', "PostsController@ajax");
```

And here is some "gibberish" when i try to dd() it:
[image: gibberish]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd()` is a laravel function and `dump()`for php. so you cannot use them from javaScript.

You cannot `dd() or dump()` from direct ajax request or JavaScript.

What you can do is, `console log your data`, or check from `browser developer portion, network tab` to see which data you are getting from the ajax response. You can find browser developer portion in,

for chrome:

```
Insepect > Network
```

for mozila:

```
Insepect Element > Network
```

If you are telling about get `var1` and `var2` on controller, you can just get them by `$request->var1` and `$request->var2.`

Comment: Ok, let reform question: how to access that data so i can return it via response()->json() like i did with others? Edit: scratch this. I found out how. Edited controller method.

Comment: Open network tab, then, load the ajax. after that you will get the list of requests. then click on the request which you want to see response. Then you will get more 5 tabs. Goto to response tab.
photo may helps you. https://imgur.com/a/LpZlVrv
all process I saw from google chrome. it may vary from browser to browser.

Comment: I think you are telling about, how to catch data? If then, and if
`return response()->json(array("var1"=> $var1, "var2"=> $var2), 200);` is your response, which you received by `response` variable, then, you can get var **`var1 = response.data.var1`**, and **`var var2 = response.data.var2`**

Comment: Didn't know it can't be done. I just trying to "hook" into them,  i just used dd() and dump() to illustrate the problem.

Comment: sorry, but i cannot understand what the problem exactly you are and where you have that problem.

Comment: Do you know, If you `dd()` anything on controller and called it from ajax, it will show on preview tab as like browser shows?

Comment: Yes. What i didn't know how to access data parameter in ajax in Laravel. Plus, if you dd($request) in controller, it shows some gibberish as shown in the image. So dd()-ing request from ajax is, at least in my case, futile in a way that it doesn't produce desired effect i.e. actually seeing values of var1 & var2 from data parameter of ajax call.

Comment: `$request->var1` and `$request->var2` Did you tried this?

Comment: To avoide **gibberish** , personally i use `return $request;` it suites me for debug the request data.

Answer (score -1):

Hasan05 was right. Just needed to know right direction. So to get data parameter of ajax request i modified ajax controller method:

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
    { 
        $var1 = $request->input('var1');
        $var2 = $request->input('var2');

        $this->authorize('view', Post::class);

        $posts = Post::orderBy("created_at","desc")->paginate(5);
        $comments = Comment::all();

        return response()->json(array("posts"=> $posts, "comments"=> $comments, "var1"=> $var1, "var2"=> $var2), 200);

    }
```

Comment: If @hasan05 was right, you should accept his answer. Not answer your own and not give him the proper credit for answering your question.

Comment: @Repox I did. Even if it didn't helped me by default, but one of his subcomments made me think in the right direction. There is no option accepting comments as accepted answers is it?